# Cassandra snapshot using nodetool

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, database-backups, nodetool

I am trying to take snapshot of my cassandra keyspace using nodetool. 
When executing `nodetool snapshot`, I am getting the following error.

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
```

After specifying host same error comes.

`nodetool -h 10.92.12.1 -p 7199 -u user -pw passpass snapshot`

Answer (score 1):

Is Cassandra running? That error usually shows when the node is not active.

If you execute `tail <path to cassandra logs>/system.log` you may get an explanation of what is happening